How to bind on function of jQuery after calling of function of jQuery
I have to call the same function after clicking a button but it's not working.
After off jQuery function trigger event is not calling.
How can I call on click function in jQuery?
Please can anyone provide suggestions to solve this issue?
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("input").on("click",function() {
    $("input").after(" Text marked!");
  });
  $("input").off("click");
  $("button").on("dblclick",function() {
    $("input").trigger("click");
  });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Hello World"><br><br>

<button>Trigger the select event for the input field</button>


It's not calling because you are removing the event listener the moment $("input").off("click"); this staement is executed.. If you want to remove the listener then figure out how and when so if it is after the event is executed once then off must be calle inside the click callback.
